# Which fast library can I use to unzip an AES encrypted file in Android

Tags: android, encryption, zip

I use library *zip4j* to unzip a file that uses AES 256bit encryption, but it unzips slowly. If you know a library that can help me to unzip faster, please let me know.

Comment: Hi new user, and welcome. You need to provide more data than that, otherwise we cannot help you (e.g. what is the current speed, what other libs have you tried). Furthermore, try and use as many relevant and popular tags as possible. Finally, don't ask, say thanks in your question and especially don't use "give me", which is considered extremely rude.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. StackOverflow is not your [personal research assistant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128553/102937). We expect you to do your own research and then come back with specific questions based on that research. You need to evaluate available libraries with your own data to see which one works for your particular needs; we can't speculate based on no information at all. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with zip4j, release build APK decompressed zipfile 10 times faster than debug build one.